# More than one Higher Order Functions in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, higher-order-functions

Can we pass two *higher order functions* or more than one, in function's parameter?
If so, then how we going to call that function which contain those two or more than one *higher order functions* as a parameter...

Comment: Just a note: the higher-order function is the one receiving functions as parameters or returning functions as results. It is not the funcion being passed

Comment: @USMANosman just because you receive answers, doesn't mean your question was appropriate. Its good for you that you receive free implementation code below, but consider doing proper research yourself before asking very basic questions here.

Answer (score 4):

Of couse you can. You can have any number of lambda parameters just like for parameters of any other type.

Even Kotlins standard library makes use of that. For example the [`generateSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html#generatesequence) function.

```
generateSequence(seedFunction = { 1 }, nextFunction = { it + 1 })
```

The only difference to a non-lambda parameter is that you can omit the parentheses if the last parameter of your function is a lambda. So you could call `generateSequence` like this too:

```
generateSequence(seedFunction = { 1 }) { it + 1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Wording

There might be a misunderstanding of what a **Higher-Order function** is:
[GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kotlin-higher-order-functions/):

> In Kotlin, a function which can accepts a function as parameter or can
>   returns a function is called Higher-Order function.

And now the definition for functions:

[Kotlinlang:](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions)

> Kotlin functions are first-class, which means that they can be stored
>   in variables and data structures, passed as arguments to and returned
>   from other higher-order functions. You can operate with functions in
>   any way that is possible for other non-function values.

### Conclusion

Functions can be passed as parameters into methods - just as many as you like. *High-order* is just a (descriptive) type, which means that your method either takes functions as parameters, or returns a function.

Example:

```
fun <T> takeFiveFunctions(
    block1 : () -> Unit,
    block2 : (T) -> Unit,
    block3 : () -> T,
    block4 : (T) -> T,
    block5 : (List<T>) -> T
) : Boolean = true

fun main() {
    takeFiveFunctions<Int>(
        block1 = { /*do something 1*/ },
        block2 = { print(it) },
        block3 = { 2 },
        block4 = { it * 3 },
        block5 = { it.first() }
    )
}
```

### EDIT

> but some other syntax says we can take out lambda from parentheses

[Kotlinlang says](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter):

> In Kotlin, there is a convention: if the last parameter of a function
>   is a function, then a lambda expression passed as the corresponding
>   argument can be placed outside the parentheses:

Using my previous example, it would look like this:

```
fun main() {
    takeFiveFunctions<Int>(
        block1 = { /*do something 1*/ },
        block2 = { print(it) },
        block3 = { 2 },
        block4 = { it * 3 }
    ) { it.first()}
}
```

Comment: yea thanks, but some other syntax says we can take out lambda from parentheses but in multiple functions i can at least have one lambda out of the parentheses rest of the lambdas will stay inside parentheses

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why not. You can just do that:

```
fun <T1, T2, T3> Collection<T1>.higherOrder(
  firstFun: (T1)->T2,
  secondFun: (T2)->T3)
: List<T3> {
  return this.map(firstFun).map(secondFun)
}
```

Invocation:

```
val result = listOf(3.14, 6.9, 42.0).higherOrder({ it.toInt() }, { it.toString() })
// ["3", "6", "42"]
```

Kotlin allows to move last lambda parameter outside parameter list, so you can also write:

```
val result = listOf(3.14, 6.9, 42.0).higherOrder({ it.toInt() }) { it.toString() }
```

But in case of multiple functional parameters, that's bad practice. The best you can do is to specify parameter names explicitly:

```
val result = listOf(3.14, 6.9, 42.0).higherOrder(
  firstFun = { it.toInt() }, 
  secondFun = { it.toString() }
)
```

Which is much more readable.